# Object prototype doesn't recognize function

Tags: javascript

I have 3 functions on an object prototype:

```
Job.prototype.postData = function(url) {
  this.getFormData();
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("position", this.position);
  formdata.append("team", this.team);
  formdata.append("details", this.details);
  $.post(url, formdata, function(response) {
    alert(response.message);
    window.location.href = '/';
  });
};

Job.prototype.createNew = function() {
  var newUrl = API_URL + "/add_listing";
  this.postData(newUrl)
};

Job.prototype.update = function() {
  var updateUrl = API_URL + "/edit_listing" + "?id=" + this.id;
  this.postData(updateUrl)
};
```

I'm attaching the last two as event handling callbacks:

```
$('#list-button').on('click',job.createNew);
$('#list-button').on('click',job.update);
```

Both of those give a `TypeError`:

> `oop.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: this.postData is not a function`

Comment: *I'm attaching the last two as event handling callbacks.* You are probably losing the context. Try to `bind` the function objects with the actual `Job` object

Comment: @thefourtheye I have edited the question to include that code too. Can you show how to bind it?

Comment: `job.createNew.bind(job)` and `job.update.bind(job)`

Comment: @thefourtheye It gives an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: You mean `$('#list-button').on('click', job.createNew.bind(job));` didn't work?

Comment: @thefourtheye sorry for the confusion. Some other part of the `postData` function was giving an error. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that the `this` context gets lost the way you're binding the event handler.

Either explicitly `bind` the context, or call the function in a way that preserves the context:

```
$('#list-button').on('click', function () { job.createNew(); });
$('#list-button').on('click', job.createNew.bind(job));
```

See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: *this* belongs to the execution context, it isn't **the** context. ;-)